# What was the punishement in the City of Judgement under Jergal rule?

Tags: forgotten-realms

In the Forgotten Realms, the souls of recently departed await on the Fugue Plane for avatars of their gods to be picked up and taken to whatever paradise they believe in. But those that were either False (betrayed their god) or Faithless (never believed in one) instead are taken to the City at the centre of this realm, where the God of Death passes his judgement over them.

With **Kelemvor** as the ruler, this place is called the City of Judgement and the punishment usually (at least for the False) is eternity without any joy. Under **Cyric** the Mad, the city was called "City of Strife" and it was a giant torture chamber both for the usual victims as well as for Cyric's faithful.

I don't know much about the rule of **Myrkul**, but judging by his penchant for necromancy, it wouldn't be hard to believe that the "City of the Dead" was exactly that - city full of ever-loyal wraiths and walking corpses. What I know, is that it was Myrkul who created the infamous "Wall of the Faithless", built from the souls of those who never worshipped anyone.

But even before Myrkul, there was **Jergal** - one of the ancient gods, the "Lord of the End of Everything". Do we know, what the City was like?